# Removing an image and adding it after div with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Firsly here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/s81rotpm/)

I have an image with class "Full", and there is a div with class "group-of-buttons", I want to remove this img and add it after the div "group-of-buttons" with js, here's the HTML Code:

```
<img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01622/nasa_1622185c.jpg" class="FULL"/>
<br><br>
<div class="group-of-buttons">
    <button class="one">One </button>
    <button class="two">Two </button>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You may use [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter):

```
$('.FULL').insertAfter('.group-of-buttons');
```

Answer (score 1):

Should do what you want. It was just a matter of using the `.insertAfter()` jQuery method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var img = $('img.FULL');
  img.insertAfter($('div.group-of-buttons'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01622/nasa_1622185c.jpg" class="FULL" />
<br>
<br>
<div class="group-of-buttons">
  <button class="one">One</button>
  <button class="two">Two</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.one').on('click', function() {
  var img = $('img.FULL');
  img.remove();
  img.insertBefore('.group-of-buttons');
});
$('.two').on('click', function() {
  var img = $('img.FULL');
  img.remove();
  img.insertAfter('.group-of-buttons');
});
```

I hope this was what you were looking to achieve example here: http://jsfiddle.net/atrifan/1ejmzkhp/

Comment: actually no, I wanted the image to be below the button

Comment: don't quite understand - so what do you want to happen on what action. Cause I remove the img and add it below the buttons when you click two and when you click one I remove it and add it above the buttons. So you can choose what you like.

Answer (score 0):

I added some extra id and div to your code. can you try this : buttons moves img from one div to another.

```
<script>
 function moveImage(movefrom,moveto,img_id) {
  imgtxt = document.getElementById(movefrom).innerHTML;
  imgobj = document.getElementById(img_id);
  document.getElementById(movefrom).removeChild(imgobj);
  document.getElementById(moveto).innerHTML = imgtxt;
 }
</script>
<div id="div1"><img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01622/nasa_1622185c.jpg" class="FULL" id="img"/></div>
<br><br>
<div class="group-of-buttons">
<button class="one" onclick="moveImage('div2','div1','img');">One </button>
<button class="two" onclick="moveImage('div1','div2','img');">Two </button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="secondary-div" id="div2">
    Secondary Div
</div>
```

I hope it helps.